# Node Js Express Iterate through array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hogan.js

I have split the STDOUT of a shell command into an array, and am passing this to hogan view engine with express.

The below is the from the router file - index.js

```
/* Test Shell Execute. */
router.get('/shell', function(req, res){
  exec('ls -1', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
       result = stdout.toString().split("\n");
       res.render('shell', { title: "File Explorer",
          array1: result[0],
          array2: result[1],
          array3: result[2],
          array4: result[3],
          array5: result[4],
          error: error,
          stderr: stderr 
     });
  });
});
```

This is working fine, however rather than manually send through each item in the array, I would like to iterate through the items at the view end and then ouput. However I am using Hogan view engine and it doesn't seem to recognise the script tag at all.

This is from my view shell.hjs file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Welcome to {{ title }}</p>
     <p>Array1 =  {{ array1 }}</p>
     <p>Array2 =  {{ array2 }}</p>
     <p>Array3 =  {{ array3 }}</p>
     <p>Array4 =  {{ array4 }}</p>
     <script>
     for(var i = 0; i > result.length; i++  ) {
         document.write('<p>' + result[i] + '</p>')
     }
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Question: What am I doing wrong and what is the best/easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since hogan.js is based on mustache.js, it's always better try to convert your arrays into objects. Try this:

```
router.get('/shell', function(req, res){
  exec('ls -1', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    result = stdout.split("\n"),
             filesArray = [];
    result.map(function (file, index) {
      filesArray.push({index: ++index, file: file});
    });
    res.render('shell', { title: "File Explorer",
      result: filesArray,
      error: error,
      stderr: stderr 
    });
  });
});
```

And, in your template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Welcome to {{ title }}</p>
    <ul>
      {{#result}}
      <li>Array{{index}} = {{file}}</li>
      {{/result}}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. Also, cute kid.